# php error working with switch for a basic menu

Tags: php, xampp, dreamweaver

i have a switch.php file to work with a menu like this:

```
<?php


switch($_GET['pag'])         
{

 default:
 include "index.php";   
 break;

 case 'about':
  include "about.php"; 
 break;

 case 'contact':
  include "contact.php"; 
 break;

}
?>
```

And then i have a contact.php file and a about.php file.
I also have a menu.php file with this code:

```
<body>


<a href="?pag=home"> HOME</a> <br>
<a href="?pag=about"> ABOUT </a> <br>
<a href="?pag=contact">CONTACT</a> <br>

</body>
```

And i also have a index.php file with things i already did, but im putting also in index.php file this:

```
<?php include "menu.php";?>
```

For i can go to other pages from the index.php page.

But when im clicking in the links Home,About,Contact nothing happens.
Anyone know why can be?

Comment: use `require_once` to avoid loops

Comment: Are the urls for Home About and Contacts in a different directory?

Comment: no..all in same folder!

Comment: It works for me. I don't know what may be wrong

Comment: I think @A.S.Roma nailed this one.

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing `switch.php`, not `index.php`? I'm curious because when I test it, it works..

Comment: i tried this <?php require_once "switch.php"  ?> in index.php but nothing happens again...:/

Comment: Try to rename `switch.php` to `index.php` and (old) `index.php` to `home.php` and change value in switch

Comment: kamil09875 acessing switch.php and not index.php where?

Comment: by browser. Do what I said, and see results

Comment: thanks for the help..but i trying what Jacob said and it works :)! thank you all

Comment: move default state of switch case to the bottom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing menu.php to include the "switch.php" filename:

```
<body>
<a href="switch.php?pag=home"> HOME</a> <br>
<a href="switch.php?pag=about"> ABOUT </a> <br>
<a href="switch.php?pag=contact">CONTACT</a> <br>
</body>
```

I suspect that you are accessing one of the pages directly, which is trying to call `?pag=X` on itself rather than switch.php

Comment: it works jacob. thank you! but its normal this happens? other users can do without "switch.php?..."

Comment: If you were accessing `yoursite/switch.php` it would have worked -- you were accessing `yoursite/` or `yousite/index.php` -- the recommendation by @kamil09875 to rename "index.php" to "home.php" and "switch.php" to "index.php", then remove the "switch.php?" change that you just added, and change `include "index.php";` to `include "home.php";` would have worked and would work without the "switch.php?..."

Comment: If this answers your question -- please mark it as accepted (otherwise, it remains an "open" question).

Answer (score 0):

May be you didn't provide the links in your other files.
For eg. no link for `home.php` in your file `contact.php`.

Ensure that all files are included and links are properly given in each file.

And try this instead

```
<?php
switch($_GET['pag'])         
{
 case 'about':
 include "about.php"; 
 break;

 case 'contact':
 include "contact.php"; 
 break;

 default:
 include "index.php";   
 break;
 }

?>
```